# Partition into pairs with minimum absolute difference, NP-hard?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, reductions, np-hard

I have a set $S$ of an even number of positive elements $2m$ and $m$ values $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_m$ where each $t_i\leq1$ for all $i$.

The question is: can you select $m$ *disjoint* pairs $(a_i,b_i)$ from $S$ such that $|a_i-b_i|\geq t_i$?

I was trying to prove that this problem is NP-hard by a reduction from [3-Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem). I failed because if I choose the numbers as in 3-partition I cannot guarantee that their absolute difference is at least $t_i$.

Do you have any hints?

Comment: Can we reduce it to a P problem then?

Comment: What's the source where you encountered this problem?  Do the pairs have to be disjoint?

Comment: It is a special case of some problem I am trying to solve. Yes, the pairs have to be disjoint.

Comment: I was mistaken. I thought the value $t_i$ was just a fixed value (not dependent on $i$); in that case, the problem is just matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce [Numeric 3D Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_3-dimensional_matching) (N3DM) to your problem.

Given an instance of N3DM $X\times Y\times Z$ with the bound $b$, say $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\},Y=\{y_1,\ldots,y_m\},Z=\{z_1,\ldots,z_m\}$, construct $2m$  elements $x_1+2M,\ldots,x_m+2M,M-y_1,\ldots,M-y_m$ and $m$ values $b-z_1+M,\ldots,b-z_m+M$ for your problem, where $M$ is a very large number. Now the constructed instance of your problem has a solution if and only if the instance of N3DM has a solution.

Comment: Thanks. Is this valid for $t_i\leq1$ for all $i$? Because we must have these constraints in the problem. Maybe if we say that $z_i\geq b+M-1$, can we?

Comment: @user199027 You can scale the problem by multiplying a large number, so it doesn't matter whether $t_i\le 1$.

Comment: When solving my problem with your created instance, I end up with $x_i+y_j+z_k\geq b$, how can I conclude that N3DM is solved? It could be the case that $x_i+y_j+z_k>b$, no?

Comment: @user199027 In N3DM, $b$ must equal to $(\sum x_i+\sum y_j+\sum z_k)/3$ (otherwise the instance has no solution trivially), so when a solution satisfies $x_i+y_j+z_k\ge b$, then it must be $x_i+y_j+z_k= b$.